Docker container progress output
I am using a docker container, that dies after the function it has to perform has been finished. I want to know is there a way to know the progress of the docker container, like how much has it been finished while it is being used, or to know which function is currently being performed?
I have tried to log all the data, as well as comparing functions to image functions but cant seem to find an answer.

First, you need to gather data on the progress. Depending on the work your function is doing, the best place to do that is probably in the function itself. Once you've gathered the data, you need to make it available outside the container. You can do that via logging or via an endpoint that you can query from outside. If you want to google for more information, some good terms are 'observability' and 'metrics'.

Firstly you have to set logs, which you say you did so to view the logs you can run the command
docker logs -f <container_id>

Additionally use can use Prometheus to collect performance metrics and Grafana to visualize them

Thank you your response, i want am creating  a progress bar sort of thing, and i dont want to add manual logs to identify a function has finished,
